# How do I perform dimensionality reduction on two independent XOR gates?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Take the probability distribution of a XOR gate in which every configuration is equally probable (configurations are given by `outcomes_sub`; the probability mass function by `pmf_xor_sub`):

```
import numpy as np
import itertools as it

outcomes_sub = [list(item) for item in list(it.product([0,1], repeat=3))]
pmf_xor_sub = np.array([1/4, 0, 0, 1/4, 0, 1/4, 1/4, 0])
```

Now take the probability distribution corresponding to two uncorrelated such XORs:

```
outcomes = [outcome1 + outcome2 for (outcome1, outcome2)
            in it.product(outcomes_sub, outcomes_sub)]
pmf_xor = [pmf1 * pmf2 for (pmf1, pmf2)
           in it.product(pmf_xor_sub, pmf_xor_sub)]
```

And create some data based on it:

```
indices = np.random.choice(len(outcomes), 10000, p=pmf_xor)
data_xor = np.array([outcomes[index] for index in indices])
```

`data_xor` looks like this:

```
array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
   ..., 
   [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
   [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

I.e., two independent XORs back to back. What's the right way to perform dimensionality reduction on it? PCA won't work (because the dependence is non-linear, right?):

```
from sklearn import decomposition
pca_xor = decomposition.PCA()
pca_xor.fit(data_xor)
```

Now, `pca_xor.explained_variance_ratio_` gives:

```
array([ 0.17145045,  0.17018817,  0.16758773,  0.16575979,  0.16410862,
    0.16090524], dtype=float32)
```

No two components stand out. I understand that a non-linear method such as kernel PCA should work here, but I am struggling to find pointers to ways of applying it to my problem.

To give a bit more context: what I am actually after is ways to bring out the structure in `data_xor`: two big XOR blobs, each of which is composed of some finer-grained stuff. If I am going about it all wrong, feel free to point that out too.